# Inverse of global sections of a sheaf of modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f \colon X \rightarrow Y $ be a morphism of schemes. Let $\mathcal F$ be a sheaf of $\mathcal O_Y$-module. Let $s$ be a global section of $\mathcal F$. How does $f$ induces an global section $f(s)$ of the inverse image of  $\mathcal F$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for arbitrary morphisms of ringed spaces (or in fact ringed topoi). A global section of $F$ is a morphism $\mathcal{O}_Y \to F$. Since pullbacks are functorial, we get a morphism $f^* \mathcal{O}_Y \to f^* F$. Since $f^* \mathcal{O}_Y = \mathcal{O}_X$, this is a global section of $f^* F$.

Comment: Can you please construct it explicitly?

Comment: @Susobhan A global section $s \in \mathcal F(Y)$ defines the morphism $\mathcal O_Y \to \mathcal F$ as $\mathcal O_X(U) \ni a \mapsto a \cdot(s\!\!\restriction_U) \in \mathcal F (U)$. Work through the construction of $f^\ast -$ and you'll get the global section of $f^\ast\mathcal F$.

Comment: Do *not* work with the construction of $f^*$. It is a functor left adjoint to $f_*$, this is how one works with it. It follows $f^* \mathcal{O}_Y = \mathcal{O}_X$ and this is what one needs here, nothing else. Notice that the explicit "construction" involves tensor products, associated sheaves, $f^{-1}$ etc. ... all this makes it usually quite impossible to work with it (but of course $f^{-1} \mathcal{O}_Y=\mathcal{O}_X$ is trivial in any case).

Comment: Oups I meant $f^* \mathcal{O}_Y=\mathcal{O}_X$ (as in the answer).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I have to say, basically every time I come on to StackExchange looking for algebraic geometry help I end up on one of your answers and without fail it has been incredibly useful. About a dozen times now your answer has been so clear and illuminated something I was stuck on. You should really consider writing a book, or do you have some expository notes or something?